# Doctrine 2, DQL Correlated subquery in LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, subquery, dql

Is it possible to translate this SQL to DQL:

```
SELECT project.*, task.*
FROM `project` 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM task 
    WHERE (task.title LIKE '%add%' OR task.description LIKE '%add%' )
) task ON project.id = task.project_id
WHERE project.id = 50
```

I need Project to be returned even if there are no tasks found.

My initial DQL was:

```
SELECT p, t FROM MyBundle:Project p 
LEFT JOIN p.tasks t
WHERE p.id = :id AND (t.title LIKE :title OR t.description LIKE :description)
ORDER BY t.id DESC
```

But this will return null if no task is found.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22673475/doctrine-2-query-builder-and-leftjoin-subquery

Comment: @redbirdo that one refers to "Querybuilder", but I might be wrong.

Comment: Sorry, yes, you're right. Although my experience is that DQL and QueryBuilder are synonymous (if I can do it in DQL there's a way to do it in QueryBuilder and vice-versa) I guess that may not always be the case or at least it may not be clear that that's the case?