# Doctrine Subquery: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 270: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_ALIASED_NAME, got 'SELECT'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to convert SQL-query using subquery into Doctrine Query Builder format (I'm writing a project with Symfony for PHP). Here's the original SQL-query:

```
SELECT b.brandid, b.brandName, b.netIncome, pc.PCompanyName, sum(ss.qty) as qty, sum(ss.sumSell) as sumSell
FROM shoesShopInnoDB3.brands b
join shoesShopInnoDB3.parentCompany pc on pc.PCompanyid=b.PCompanyid
join shoesShopInnoDB3.shoes s on s.brandid=b.brandid
join (SELECT s.shoesid as ssShoesid, s.shoesTitle as ssShoesTitle, b.brandid as ssBrandid, b.brandName as ssBrandName, sum(oi.quantity) as qty, s.shoesPrice*sum(oi.quantity) as sumSell
FROM shoesShopInnoDB3.shoes s
join shoesShopInnoDB3.brands b on b.brandid=s.brandid
join shoesShopInnoDB3.orderItems oi on oi.shoesid=s.shoesid
join shoesShopInnoDB3.orders o on o.orderid=oi.orderid
group by s.shoesid) as ss on ss.ssShoesid=s.shoesid
group by b.brandid
order by b.brandName
```

Here's my Doctrine query:

```
public function reportBrands()
    {
        $subqb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
        $subqb 
            ->select('s.shoesid as ssshoesid, s.shoestitle as ssshoestitle, b.brandid as ssbrandid, b.brandname as ssbrandname, sum(oi.quantity) as qty, s.shoesprice*sum(oi.quantity) as sumsell')
            ->from('App\Entity\Shoes', 's')
            ->join('App\Entity\Brands', 'b', 'with', 'b.brandid=s.brandid')
            ->join('App\Entity\Orderitems', 'oi', 'with', 'oi.shoesid=s.shoesid')
            ->join('App\Entity\Orders', 'o', 'with', 'o.orderid=oi.orderid')
            ->groupBy('s.shoesid')
        ;
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('b');
        $qb
            ->select('b.brandid, b.brandname, b.netincome, pc.pcompanyname, sum(ss.qty) as qty, sum(ss.sumsell) as sumsell')
            ->join('App\Entity\Parentcompany','pc', 'with', 'pc.pcompanyid=b.pcompanyid')
            ->join('App\Entity\Shoes', 's', 'with', 's.brandid=b.brandid')
            ->join($subqb->getDQL(), 'ss', 'with', 'ss.ssshoesid=s.shoesid')
            ->groupBy('b.brandid')
            ->orderBy('b.brandname')
        ;
        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult(); //error here
    }
```

But I get the next error:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 270: Error: Expected
> Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_ALIASED_NAME, got 'SELECT'

EDIT: I tried to use DBAL QueryBuilder:

```
public function reportBrands()
    {
        $qb = $this->_em->getConnection()->createQueryBuilder('b');
        $qb2 = $qb;
        $qb2
            ->select('s.shoesid as ssshoesid, s.shoestitle as ssshoestitle, b.brandid as ssbrandid, b.brandname as ssbrandname, sum(oi.quantity) as qty, s.shoesprice*sum(oi.quantity) as sumsell')
            // ->from('App\Entity\Brands', 'b')
            ->join('App\Entity\Shoes', 's', 'with', 'b.brandid=s.brandid')
            ->join('App\Entity\Orderitems', 'oi', 'with', 'oi.shoesid=s.shoesid')
            ->join('App\Entity\Orders', 'o', 'with', 'o.orderid=oi.orderid')
            ->groupBy('s.shoesid')
        ;

        $qb = $this->_em->getConnection()->createQueryBuilder('b');
        $qb
            ->select('b.brandid, b.brandname, b.netincome, pc.pcompanyname, sum(ss.qty) as qty, sum(ss.sumsell) as sumsell')
            // ->from('App\Entity\Brands', 'b')
            ->join('App\Entity\Parentcompany','pc', 'with', 'pc.pcompanyid=b.pcompanyid')
            ->join('App\Entity\Shoes', 's', 'with', 's.brandid=b.brandid')
            ->join($qb2 . 'ss', 'with', 'ss.ssshoesid=s.shoesid')
            ->groupBy('b.brandid')
            ->orderBy('b.brandname')
        ;
        return $qb->execute();

    }
```

But I got the next error:

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT b.brandid, b.brandname,
> b.netincome, pc.pcompanyname, sum(ss.qty) as qty, sum(ss.sumsell) as
> sumsell GROUP BY b.brandid ORDER BY b.brandname ASC':
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY
> b.brandid ORDER BY b.brandname ASC' at line 1

What code changes should I do?

Comment: The **ORM** DQL and as such the query builder does not support JOIN subqueries, you would need to either use a [JOIN `WITH` subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33137173/1144627) or a  [native query and result-set mapping](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/native-sql.html) to convert the result into entities.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Doctrine 2 query builder and leftJoin subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22673475/doctrine-2-query-builder-and-leftjoin-subquery)

Comment: No, it doesn't answer, still the same error

Comment: Look at my query, I need to get a sum of sum I get in subquery

Comment: I saw the query, as I stated and as clarified by the duplicate question & answer, what you're attempting to accomplish with DQL by using a subquery as the JOIN table in the ORM query builder is not supported. You would need to convert the clause to be DQL compatible, use a native query or the DBAL query builder instead. It is a limitation of how the ORM builds relationships between *objects* instead of the data.

Comment: I tried, but still get the same error

Comment: **You can not use the ORM query builder or Entity references to execute your query**. If you're getting the same error, you are not using the [DBAL query builder](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.12/reference/query-builder.html) as I suggested, `$qb = $this->_em->getConnection()->createQueryBuilder()`.  You may also want to checkout what one of the [Doctrine devs says about using the ORM](https://ocramius.github.io/doctrine-best-practices/#/16) for reporting purposes.

Comment: I tried to use DBAL query builder, but got another error. I edited a post with new code. Please take a look

Comment: The DBAL query builder uses table names instead of entity names and the `JOIN` syntax is slightly different. `->innerJoin($from_alias, $table_name, $alias, $on_criteria)`. So `->innerJoin('b', 'parentCompany', 'pc', 'pc.pcompanyid = b.pcompanyid')` and your subquery would need to be wrapped in `()`, like so `->innerJoin('s', '(' . $qb2->getSQL() . ')',  'ss', 'ss.ssshoesid=s.shoesid')` You would also need to specify the `from`, since the connection is global and not related to the current entity repository. `->from('brands', 'b')`